# Facebook API - Custom Audience from contact data

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

does any one has experience with using Custom Audience API in order to create audience for contact data of people outside of U.S.?

Part of the API which i refer to is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/users/

As you can see, documentation lacks of explanation in what format should be data for COUNTRY field provided. Also I don't know how to format data for ST field if the country is outside of US. Should I use some region name or just leave it blank?

I uploaded 1000 users and nobody has been recognized so I suppose that I just did not format data properly.

Sample request: payload={"schema":["FN","LN","CT","ST","COUNTRY"],"is_raw":true,"data":[["adam","nowak","wroclaw","","poland"]]}&access_token=____&format=json

As you can see I left state field blank, and provided country in English translation and lower caps. It is possible that valid value is e.g. PL a not "poland". Also any information about what should be filled in state field would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure Country is even an option? It's not listed in the docs. If it's supported then it's most definitely a two letter code, as that's the format  used throughout the api.

Comment: COUNTRY is listed in docs. It's in section Updating -> Parameters. Expand "payload" parameter in the table and you'll see that COUNTRY is listed as a possible key in the schema.

Comment: You are right, sneaky fb docs. I'm 99% sure it's a two letter code, it's what used for lookalikes and for general location targeting.

Comment: Right, but then there is still a problem with ST field. I created a bug on FB and so far they just told me that probably this feature is available only in US and UK. But it's not confirmed yet - I'm waiting for a definite answer.

Comment: do you have a link to the bug report ?

Comment: Yes, they updated documentation since my last comment: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1368821426477257/

But still they didn't told me specifically what are possible values of state filed in Poland.